# Separate a string into different names then reorder each - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

Basically I have a string with the value:

Bruce Lee, Jackie Chan, Micky Rourke, Vinnie Jones,

what I'd like to do is convert the above into something like:

Lee, B., Chan, J., Rourke, M., Jones, V.

I'm sure this can be done but i'm totally new to string manipulation and iPhone development. NSScanner seems useful but after reading the documentation I'm still unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is an impossible problem to solve reliably. Think of names like "van der Something" or those with two surnames. What about multiple first names? Those who go by their full (given, middle, family) names? What of those with extremely long multi-word names? There are *many* nationalities and the format commonly referred to as "Christian names" in Western culture is by no means the majority or any kind of standard.

In general you can separate "tokens" (words) by using -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] (passing a space as the separator), which hands you an array of substrings, but you'll likely have to provide additional UI to allow the user to correct any names that don't follow the traditional Westerner name style (Firstname Lastname).

As for reordering you can sort arrays easily by using NSMutableArray's many -sort... methods or NSArray's many -sortedArrays... methods. The documentation is your friend.

Comment: thanks for such a quick and informative response, could I use -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] but instead seperate it by say", " so each item in the array is each fullname at the least.

Comment: It would stand to reason that since @", " is another string the -componentsSeparatedByString: method would accept that, yes. :-)

Comment: cool! sorry to keep pestering but if I can get each name into a row in a list, is there a way to shorten all but the last word in the row to its first initial i.e

Jackie Edward Chan = J E Chan

This would not be perfect but it would help!

Comment: As long as you're fine with blindly shortening regardless of the actual name, then you could separate each name string in your array into their own components (arrays) by using a the space separator I originally mentioned. Then take the first character of all but the -lastObject of that array with -substringToIndex:1 ..., then building your string with maybe NSString's -stringWithFormat: or NSMutableString's -appendFormat: to add your periods, spaces, etc. with the initials and the -lastObject of your name components.